# How can you convert this single slideshow script to multiple slideshows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have found this code online which can create a slideshow perfectly fine

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-auto-playing-slideshow/

Can somebody tell me how to adjust the code so it can work for multiple slideshows?

I have tried many attempts and failed and was hoping someone can work it out.

Thanks
Daniel

Comment: It might help to show what you've got so far and what's going wrong. If you use a class selector rather than an ID, you can iterate through those elements and initialize a slideshow on each one. The article you referenced links to a [similar one](https://snook.ca/archives/javascript/simplest-jquery-slideshow) with a [demo page](https://snook.ca/technical/fade/fade.html) that shows multiple slideshows. In the source code you'll see something like: `$('.multipleslides').each(function() { // scope everything for each slideshow ...`

Answer (score 0):

Use `class` instead of `id`, then loop through the slideshow, ie like this:

```js
$.each($(".slideshow > div:not(:first-child)"), function() {
  $(this).hide();
});

setInterval(function() { 
  $.each($(".slideshow"), function() {
    $(this).children().first()
      .fadeOut(1000)
      .next()
      .fadeIn(1000)
      .end()
      .appendTo(this);
   });
},  3000);
```

```css
.slideshow { 
    margin: 50px auto; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 240px; 
    height: 240px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

.slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px; 
    left: 10px; 
    right: 10px; 
    bottom: 10px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slideshow">
   <div>
     <img src="//farm6.static.flickr.com/5224/5658667829_2bb7d42a9c_m.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="//farm6.static.flickr.com/5230/5638093881_a791e4f819_m.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     Pretty cool eh? This slide is proof the content can be anything.
   </div>
</div>

<div class="slideshow">
   <div>
     <img src="//farm6.static.flickr.com/5224/5658667829_2bb7d42a9c_m.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="//farm6.static.flickr.com/5230/5638093881_a791e4f819_m.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     Pretty cool eh? This slide is proof the content can be anything.
   </div>
</div>

<div class="slideshow">
   <div>
     <img src="//farm6.static.flickr.com/5224/5658667829_2bb7d42a9c_m.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="//farm6.static.flickr.com/5230/5638093881_a791e4f819_m.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     Pretty cool eh? This slide is proof the content can be anything.
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly first time, Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Hi would you be interested in working on a banner and video manager project with me?

Comment: Sorry, have no time for that - but good luck! If it works, can you please accept my answer as a correct answer? Thanks!

Comment: ok sure no worries about the time issues, i tried to accept the answer yet there is no button for some reason, i will see if the moderators can accept the answer for me.

Comment: The accept-icon is below the "vote up" and "vote down"-icons left of the answers :)